# Setting styles through code on html elements. Is there better way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I came across some code like this:

```
public string IsAdmin()
{
    string style = "";

    if(EditUserName == "")
    {
        style = "visibility:hidden;display:none";
    }
    return style;
}
```

Then in the html, I see something like this:

```
 <table style='<%= IsAdmin() %>'>
 </table>
```

The above doesn't seem the best way to do this.  Is there a more efficient and alternative way to set the style of html elements programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start it off by saying that it's generally a bad practice to set inline styles on elements -- especially on server-side code.

Style should generally be set through external style sheets.

When manipulating the DOM on the client-side, there are a number of acceptable ways of setting an element's style.  Generally, it's efficient for coders to use a library like jQuery.

Comment: +1 It would be much better to follow this advice and use CSS classes.  Then determine at server-time whether to include user.css or admin.css and re-style as needed.

Comment: He may still need this technique in order to set the CSS class, which could be determining whether an item should be initially visible.

Comment: +1. Embedding inline CSS is just as evil as the old-school FONT tag. Don't do it. Instead, create a separate CSS file with a rule for "table.admin", and set the table CLASS attribute to "admin" based on your logic. Keep logic and design concerns separate.

Comment: The whole asp.net domain is so weird and ... wrong ... for writing webapps.

Comment: I 100% agree with the inline styles

Answer (score 4):

If you use this arrangement:

```
<table runat="server" ID="tableElement">
</table>
```

then, you can do something like this:

```
HtmlTable table = (tableElement as HtmlTable);
table.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");
table.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility, "hidden");
```

**Edit**

In light of the other suggestions, you would instead use this technique like this:

```
table.Style.Add("class", "whatever");
```

Comment: Thanks, s-o-m-e-times we do want to do a dirty old inline style in say an html email, so thanks@

Answer (score 3):

To me it looks like what you really want is visibility based on permissions not really styles, why not do this:

**Markup:**

```
<table runat="server" visible='<%= IsVisible() %>'>
</table>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected bool IsVisible()
{
    bool result= true;

    if(EditUserName == string.empty)
    {
        result= false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This could cause a negative effect if Javascript is planning on dynamically showing the table later on, because setting the table to not Visible prevents the HTML from writing to the browser

Comment: @bendewey - Can you explain a bit further?  Do you mean setting the table's visibility through it's style attribute or the visible attribute?

Comment: The Visible attribute when using runat="server" will not render the HTML.  (ie. you javascript won't find the element because it won't exist)